# How can I sum the same column differently depending on another column type

Tags: t-sql, dynamic, alteryx

I have a SQL Query I want to create in Alteryx.  This query goes through an Invoicing table and sums up different charges depending on the location that is associated with it.  So each location can have different types for each column.  Below is an example:

```
Location    FreightCharge   InvoiceCharge
A           FRT             IVC
B           FRT, CHG        IVC, DTL
```

Using a query with a case statement worked fine when I only had one location to worry about.  Now I will potentially have hundreds.  I created a Locations table that has the types in it (the table above).  But I'm not convinced it's the right way to do this.

ultimately I would either want a SQL Statement (alteryx) that can do this from the ground up or (more likely) a workflow I can use to loop through locations which links to my reference table and automatically tallies this data.

Any ideas?

However, it would be nice if I could run this for each location, appending it to an invoice table.

I've tried creating a reference table and joining it to my main invoicing query but I can't get it to filter by the correct data.  I've considered creating a Alteryx or SSIS Package that loops through each record, however I don't need to loop through things one record at a time. Just one location at a a time.

This would go into a table like this for location A:

```
    Select Location, InvoiceNumber, Case WHEN InvoiceType IN('FRT') THEN InvoiceAmount Else 0 End as FreightCharge  --**I want this to be dynamic depending on location, Case WHEN InvoiceType IN('IVC','DTL') then InvoiceAmount Else 0 End as InvoiceCharge --**I want this to be dynamic depending on location From Invoicing Where InvoiceDate = Today
```

I would want an invoicing table with all locations and their summed values (how they should sum according to the reference table) all in one table.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you organize your lookup table as:

```
Location GroupLabel  InvoiceType
A        Freight     FRT
A        Invoice     IVC
B        Freight     FRT
B        Freight     CHG
B        Invoice     IVC
B        Invoice     DTL
```

And it sounds like your data is something like...

```
Location  InvoiceNumber  InvoiceAmount  InvoiceType
A         1              1.00           FRT
A         1              2.00           IVC
A         2              3.00           FRT
A         2              4.00           IVC
B         3              5.00           FRT
B         3              6.00           IVC
B         4              7.00           CHG
B         4              8.00           DTL
```

Then, I think the following would provide what you're after...

```
Select
    i.Location
  , i.InvoiceNumber
  , l.GroupLabel
  , Sum(i.Amount)
From
    Invoicing i
    Inner Join LookupTable l
       on l.Location = i.Location
      and l.InvoiceType = i.InvoiceType
Group By
    i.Location
  , i.InvoiceNumber
  , l.GroupLabel
```

In Alteryx, it should be pretty straightforward to do the Join on both Location and InvoiceType before doing an Aggregation grouped by the three fields shown and summing InvoiceAmount.